# Selenium Page Source

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello Im trying getting full html code of my gmail account page. But i have a problem i can't get working html code. This is what im getting:

[image]

I copied this codes and putted a notepad then i saved it as .html and i can't get this:

[image]

im getting this:

[image]

And my code:

```
import time
import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("my link to gmail account")
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

How i can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail's code is **auto-generated**. It is not like a normal website whose code never changes.

If you want an `html` page that works tho, go back to that page and **press** <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: How i can do this process in code? Thanks.

Comment: I do know how to do this in python... I would suggest you open a new question for that.